# C++ Includes and Circular dependencies

Tags: c++, include, circular-dependency

***UPDATE:*** Let me clarify my files and reiterate my question:

***main.h***

```
#include "other.h"

class MyClass
{
    public:
    void MyMethod();
    void AnotherMethod();

    OtherClass test;
}
```

***main.cpp***

```
#include "main.h"

void MyClass::MyMethod()
{
    OtherClass otherTemp;     // <--- instantitate OtherClass object
    otherTemp.OtherMethod();  // <--- in this method here, is where I want to also call MyClass::AnotherMethod()
}

void MyClass::AnotherMethod()
{
    // Some code
}
```

***other.h***

```
class OtherClass
{
    public:
    void OtherMethod();
}
```

***other.cpp***

```
#include "other.h"
void OtherClass::OtherMethod()
{
    // !!!! This is where I want to access MyClass::AnotherMethod(). How do I do it?
    // I can't just instantiate another MyClass object can I? Because if you look above in 
    // main.cpp, this method (OtherClass::OtherMethod()) was called from within
    // MyClass::MyMethod() already.
}
```

So basically what I want is this: you instantiate object A, which in turn instantiates object B, which in turn calls a method that is from object A. I'm sure something like this is possible, but it might just be poor design on my part. Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to access it in the `.h`?

Comment: For another shot at the same kind of question, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655096/c-class-its-base-class-and-circular-include-includes

Comment: I didn't mean for anyone to assume that I was doing my implementation's in the header file. I've reiterated and clarified my original question.

Comment: Ok, have you tried it? Depending on how you implement it you might end up with infinite recursion (`OtherMethod` calling `AnotherMethod` and ...) but that has nothing to do with cyclic dependencies --even if you should try to avoid cycles anyway.

Comment: I've updated my answer to address the call to AnotherMethod

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some do one .h/.cpp per class:

#### my.h

```
#ifndef MY_H
#define MY_H
#include "other.h"
class MyClass
{
    public:
    void MyMethod();

    OtherClass test;
}
#endif // MY_H
```

#### other.h

```
#ifndef OTHER_H
#define OTHER_H
class OtherClass
{
    public:
    void Othermethod();
}
#endif // OTHER_H
```

#### my.cpp

```
#include "my.h"
void MyClass::MyMethod() { }
```

#### other.cpp

```
#include "other.h"
#include "my.h"
void OtherClass::OtherMethod)()
{
   // (ab)using MyClass...
}
```

If you're using only Visual Studio, you could use `#pragma once` instead of `#ifndef xx_h #define xx_h #endif // xx_h`.
EDIT: as the comment says, and also the related [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once), `#pragma once` is also supported (at least) by GCC.

UPDATE:
About the updated question, unrelated to #include, but more about passing objects around...

MyClass already has an embedded instance of OtherClass, `test`. So, in MyMethod, it's probably more like:

```
void MyClass::MyMethod()
{
    test.OtherMethod();
}
```

And if OtherMethod needs to access the MyClass instance, pass this instance to OtherMethod either as a reference, or a pointer:

#### By reference

```
class OtherClass { public: void OtherMethod(MyClass &parent); }

void MyClass::MyMethod() { test.OtherMethod(*this); }

void OtherClass::OtherMethod(MyClass &parent)
{
   parent.AnotherMethod();
}
```

#### By Pointer

```
class OtherClass { public: void OtherMethod(MyClass *parent); }

void MyClass::MyMethod() { test.OtherMethod(this); }

void OtherClass::OtherMethod(MyClass *parent)
{
   if (parent == NULL) return;  // or any other kind of assert
   parent->AnotherMethod();
}
```

Comment: #pragma once is supported in the GCC suite as well.

Comment: One class per header file (where the header file is named after the class) is a pretty good way to go. It's always very easy to find what you're looking for that way.

Answer (score 2):

Define the function outside of either class in a C++ source file, not in the header:

```
void OtherClass :: Othermethod() {
   // call whatever you like here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a .cpp file:

```
#include "main.h"

void OtherClass::Othermethod()
{
    MyClass m; //ok :)
    m.MyMethod(); //also ok.
}
```

Implementations don't belong in headers anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Just #include it inside other.cpp