# Proper way to #include when there is a circular dependency?

Tags: c++

I'm using #pragma once, not #include guards  on all my h files. What do I do if a.h needs to #include b.h and b.h needs to #include a.h?

I'm getting all sorts if errors because by doing this, the pragma once takes effect and one of them is missing each other. How should I do this.

Thanks

Comment: Many duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748624/circular-dependencies-of-declarations, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655096/c-class-its-base-class-and-circular-include-includes to name a few

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to forward declare the definitions you need.  So if A uses B as a parameter value, you need to forward declare B, and vice versa.

It could be that just forward declaring the class names:

```
 class A;
 class B;
```

solves your problems.

The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-to-use-forward-declaration) provides some additional guidance.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to refactor some portion of the files `a.h` and `b.h` into a third file say `c.h`, and include it from both `a.h` and `b.h`. This way, the latter two would no longer need to mutually include each other.

Another possibility is to merge the separate header files into one.

A third possibility is the situation when two classes legitimately need to refer to each other. In such cases you *have to* use pointers. Moreover, you can forward declare the class instead of including its header file. [Mentioned also by [jdv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/180326/jdv)] For example,

```
// file a.h
struct B;
struct A { B * b_ };

// file b.h
struct A; 
struct B { A * a_; };
```

However, without knowing your particular situation it is difficult to provide specific suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what is needed from each other's header file. IF it's a class definition, but it only is using a pointer to the class, then instead of including the head file just put in a forward declaration like:

`class MyClassA;`

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this issue is 'forward declaration'.

If you have a class or a function that needs to be used in 2 headers one of the headers needs to forward declare the used class or type.
Or you need to consider to restructure your headers.

This is a common beginner issue that circular dependencies are causing such issues. If you google on 'forward declaration' will find tons of results.

Since your question was too unspecific I can't give you an exact answer, sorry for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use incomplete types, but you can just forward declare them. You just tell the compiler:"Don't get syntax errors, I know what i am doing". Which means that the linker will go and find complete types from libraries whatsoever.