# C++ linking header files and class files

Tags: c++, oop, g++

I'm making some header files that I'll be using, so far I have 4, which are named: `name.h` `patrons.h` `library.h` and `book.h`. My problem is this: `library.h` contains a `book` object which is found in the `book.h` class. `patrons.h` contains objects found in the `book.h` class. So most if not all of the class interact with each other in some way.

When I try to compile the header files I get this error:

```
patrons.h:12:20: error: #include nested too deeply
patrons.h:13:18: error: #include nested too deeply
patrons.h:14:19: error: #include nested too deeply
patrons.h:15:18: error: #include nested too deeply
patrons.h:16:21: error: #include nested too deeply
patrons.h:17:18: error: #include nested too deeply
In file included from name.h:18:0,
                 from library.h:16,
```

and this loops through and gives me the identical error for each file. I assume this is because the `book.h` has an `#include "library.h` and so does `patrons.h`, so it causes a loop of some sorts. How do I fix this? I'm new to C++ so please excuse me if it is hard to understand.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021720/c-nested-include-avoiding-include-nested-too-deeply-error

Comment: Instead of including other headers in header files, you should forward declare referenced classes and structs as much as possible, and include the headers with the full declaration in your translation units (.cpp files).

Comment: @MikołajMularczyk Thanks, that fixes that. I have some `enum` and other `define` included in the header file. I am now getting the error that they're `not declared in that scope` even though the header file it is linked to contains the definitions. Is there a way to make this definitions `public`?