# why do i constantly have an error in compilation: include nested too deeply c++

Tags: c++, nested, include, mingw

whenever i try to build my code, the compiler show this error: include nested too deeply error c++, and when i try to click Abort compilation .. a page with a cctype code is opened.

i'm using dev C++ , and i tried to uninstall and remove the configuration files, but nothing changed

no matter what code i write, even when i write the Hello World code, this error still exist!
this is the code i'm trying right now:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
main ()
{

    cout << "hello world! ";
}
```

kindly see the below pictures.

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bg0mm.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6XfZ.png)

Comment: Would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021720/c-nested-include-avoiding-include-nested-too-deeply-error

Comment: i'm sorry but no.

Comment: Please post code as *text*, *not* as images.

Comment: you can see the code as a text now.

Comment: Not sure if it's the *only* problem but the code shown has no return type specified for `main`.

Comment: even if i write "void main" .. the same problem appears.

Comment: `void main` is wrong. `main` *must always* return `int`.

Comment: Still the same problem even after I write “int main”

Comment: Please, post compiler diagnostics as _text_, _not_ as images.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you've overwritten a file which you shouldn't have, cctype.  You should do as the other comments recommend, but also restore cctype and be sure to never edit parts of your compiler's standard library.

Comment: How can I restore it?

Comment: If you edited it recently, you may be able to open cctype and hit ctrl+z until it doesn't change anything anymore.  Otherwise, you should probably remove and reinstall gcc from mingw.  I haven't used mingw in quite a while so I can't help you there...but I'm getting the impression that it is included as part of Dev-C++ IDE.  I would resolve this by uninstalling and reinstalling Dev-C++.

Comment: uninstalling it and reinstalling didn't solve the problem :(
do u have another suggestions ?

Comment: You should open another question.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I solved this issue recently when it happened to me. What I did is that I deleted all C++ Editor related and C++ Compiler related files and then re-installed the Editor. I personally use Dev C++ for light use and during installation, you have to basically check one box which says that do you want to delete older files related to this compiler. Then you are all set!